# Checking SOLR indexing progress

Tags: solr, indexing, alfresco

I have started a SOLR re-index procedure on a huge Alfresco repository. However the process gets stuck sometimes and I would like to know on which file did it stop.
I can't see it in the logs (INFO logging level) or on the SOLR status page.

My question is as follows: is there any way of checking which file is being indexed at the moment?

Comment: Have you checked out https://wiki.alfresco.com/wiki/Alfresco_And_SOLR#Checking_the_status_of_the_Solr_index and the status information? How are you indexing the repository?

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I invoked `/cores?action=REINDEX`. I have checked out earlier what you provided and unfortunately it was no help, there's no information about file being indexed.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Ok, I found it myself. I'm posting this for people facing similar problem.

To ask SOLR how is indexing going try this url:

```
/solr/admin/cores?action=SUMMARY&wt=xml
```

Most interesting values here are:

```
<long name="Approx transactions remaining">0</long>
<str name="Approx transaction indexing time remaining">0 Seconds</str>
```

which tell how much work SOLR thinks it has to do.

To get more information about the status hit:

```
/solr/admin/cores?action=REPORT&wt=xml
```

to get `<long name="Index error count">` to tell how much documents are not searchable. You can also get what caused this hitting

```
solr/afts?q=ID:ERROR-*&wt=xml
```

also if you have more than 50 problematic documents add `&rows=` providing number of problematic indexes you want to retrieve.

*Note:* If it's **Alfresco's** SOLR then the link goes: `solr/alfresco/afts?q=ID:ERROR-*&wt=xml`

Comment: The URI seems to be `/solr/admin/cores?action=STATUS&wt=xml` in the latest Solr.